# How to load device tree overlay on kernel 3.19+

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded, device-tree

Kernel 3.19 (re-)introduced Device Tree Overlays. I am on Linux kernel `3.19.4`, via Fedora (`3.19.4-200.fc21.armv7hl`).

I have an overlay file `overlay.dts` as described in the [documentation](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/devicetree/overlay-notes.txt).

[overlay.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/of/overlay.c) contains functions to work with overlays, including to functions to load an overlay.

Does the kernel check any paths for overlays to load? If so, where? If not, how can I load my overlay?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience (3.8-3.14), DTB loading is actually the jurisdiction of the boot-loader, rather than the kernel itself. I've used u-boot for this - u-boot can load the compiled device-tree file (man dtc) from an EXT2-based filesystem to a known location in RAM, which is then specified in the kernel command line.

Which boot-loader are you using?